# Approximation by convolution and cut-off function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

let u be a $L^p$-function on the upper half-ball with radius $R$ and center at 0 $B_R^+\subset \mathbb{R}^m_+$ with boundary condition u=g on flat boundary of the half-ball.
I construct the following approximation: 
$$
u^{\varepsilon}(x):=g(x)+\int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}\zeta(z^m)\cdot (u-g)(z)\cdot \eta_{\varepsilon}(x-z)dz,
$$
where $0\leq\zeta\leq1$ is a cut-off function with $\zeta=0$ on $[0,2\varepsilon]$ and $\zeta=1$ on $[3\varepsilon,\infty]$.
Now, let $x^m>2\varepsilon$. I want to show that $u^{\varepsilon}$ tends to $u$ for $\varepsilon\searrow0$ for a.e. $x$. My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\vert u^{\varepsilon}(x)-u(x)\vert&=\bigg\vert g(x)-u(x)+\int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}\zeta(z^m)\cdot (u-g)(z)\cdot \eta_{\varepsilon}(x-z)dz\bigg\vert\\
&=\bigg\vert\int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}[\zeta(z^m)\cdot (u-g)(z)-(u-g)(x)]\cdot \eta_{\varepsilon}(x-z)dz\bigg\vert\\
&\leq \Vert \eta\Vert_{\infty}\varepsilon^{-m} \int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}\vert\zeta(z^m)\cdot (u-g)(z)-(u-g)(x)\vert dz\\
&\leq \Vert \eta\Vert_{\infty}\varepsilon^{-m} \int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}\vert(\zeta(z^m)-1)\cdot (u-g)(z)\vert dz\\
&\quad+\Vert \eta\Vert_{\infty}\varepsilon^{-m} \int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}\vert (u-g)(z)-(u-g)(x)\vert dz\\
&\leq \Vert \eta\Vert_{\infty}\varepsilon^{-m} \int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}\vert\zeta(z^m)-1\vert \vert (u-g)(z)\vert dz\\
&\quad+\Vert \eta\Vert_{\infty}\vert B^+_{1}(0)\vert\dfrac{1}{\vert B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)\vert} \int_{B^+_{\varepsilon}(x)}\vert (u-g)(z)-(u-g)(x)\vert dz
\end{align*}
For $\varepsilon\searrow0$ the second term tends to 0 due to Lebesgue Differentiation theorem. What about the first term? How can i argue that this converges also to 0?

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is just an $L^p$ function, then it is defined up to sets of Lebesgue measure zero, so specifying $u=g$ on the flat part of the semi-ball does not mean anything. You will not be able to make  the first term converge. Lebesgue differentiation theorem is for every point up to a set of Lebesgue measure zero. What you need is $u$ to be in some Sobolev space and then  use the theory of traces.

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually u is in $W^{2,2}(B_R^+)$ and satisfies in the trace sense the boundary conditions $u=g$ and $Du=Dg$ on the flat boundary of $B_R^+$. I thought for computing the above limit it doesn't play a role for all these details.

Comment: Could you give a good reference where i can read about the theory of traces?

Comment: Necas, Direct Methods in the Theory of Elliptic Equations or Leoni, A First Course in Sobolev Spaces or Evans Partial Differential Equations

Comment: OK in $W^{2,2}(B^+_R)$ the problem makes sense but you are using the entire ball in the integral while the function $u$ is defined only in the half ball...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I changed the integration. Are my steps proper so far?

Comment: I don't know. It's not clear what you are trying to do.  If you want to use the theory of mollifiers then you need the entire ball. Mollifiers do not work well near the boundary.  You might need to extend first $u$ to the entire ball and then mollify the extension. Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60550/discussion-between-serdar-and-gio67).

Comment: sorry but I am traveling these days